# Background color of caption text within a bootstrap carousel will not resize

Tags: html, css

I want a background around the text in the carousel but it goes far beyond the edges of the text. I've tried a few things, mostly working with the padding and background modifiers but I can't figure it out.

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.carousel .item {   
    max-height: 300px;
}

.carousel-inner img {   
    width: 50%;
}

.carousel-caption {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/Boxes.png">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h2>2ND GENERATION LAUNCH</h2>
         <p>Our new 2nd generation Ryzen processors have been released!<br>An across the board 30% increase in performance means that your productivity<br>will be better than it ever has been.</p>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">GET YOURS</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/dell-ryzen.jpg">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h2>DELL COMPUTERS ARE NOW PACKING RYZEN</h2>
         <p>Dell has partnered with us to put Ryzen in several of their system lines.<br>From their Alienware gaming computers to their precision workstations,<br>Ryzen will be the beating heart of one of the largest PC manufacturers in the world.</p>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">GET YOURS</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/Zen.png">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h2>ZEN+ IS HERE</h2>
         <p>With the release of </p>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">GET YOURS</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```